# Python Pandas: how to shift row content on each rows independently to produce Covid chart from the 100th case

Tags: python, pandas, row

This is my first question on Stack overflow and I have been searching extensively for similar Q&A without success yet.

I am working with the [Covid dataset](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv) and try to produce a chart without date timeline but with a count of days since the 100th case, [similar to this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzWUu.jpg)

To do so I am looking for a code allowing me to shift the row content over the column(s) with 0 for each row:
[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ONn.jpg)

**Problem:** I thought of using DropNa here but it would delete columns where other rows would have an actual number... Any suggestions ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try something like this:

```
df_confirmed = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv')
df_con = df_confirmed.set_index(['Country/Region', 'Province/State']).drop(['Lat', 'Long'], axis=1)
df_con.mask((df_con == 0).cumprod(axis=1).astype(bool)).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().to_numpy()), axis=1)
```

Output(print head(5) of result):

```
                                0    1    2    3    4    5     6     7     8   \
Country/Region Province/State                                                   
Thailand       NaN             2.0  3.0  5.0  7.0  8.0  8.0  14.0  14.0  14.0   
Japan          NaN             2.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  4.0  4.0   7.0   7.0  11.0   
Singapore      NaN             1.0  3.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  7.0   7.0  10.0  13.0   
Nepal          NaN             1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   
Malaysia       NaN             3.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  7.0  8.0   8.0   8.0   8.0   

                                 9   ...     50     51     52     53     54  \
Country/Region Province/State        ...                                      
Thailand       NaN             19.0  ...   70.0   75.0   82.0  114.0  147.0   
Japan          NaN             15.0  ...  639.0  701.0  773.0  839.0  825.0   
Singapore      NaN             16.0  ...  200.0  212.0  226.0  243.0  266.0   
Nepal          NaN              1.0  ...    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0   
Malaysia       NaN              8.0  ...  428.0  566.0  673.0  790.0  900.0   

                                   55      56     57     58      59  
Country/Region Province/State                                        
Thailand       NaN              177.0   212.0  272.0  322.0   411.0  
Japan          NaN              878.0   889.0  924.0  963.0  1007.0  
Singapore      NaN              313.0   345.0  385.0  432.0     NaN  
Nepal          NaN                1.0     1.0    NaN    NaN     NaN  
Malaysia       NaN             1030.0  1183.0    NaN    NaN     NaN  

[5 rows x 60 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you Scott ! From your code I understand that changing '(df_con == 0)' by (df_con <= 100) will allow us to set the start counter at 100 cases

Comment: Yes, Adrien.  That is correct, that should work as you state.